# How to bind event to element *after* loading it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I tried with `when().then()` + `bind()` :

```
$.when(loadImage('./content/tekst_naczynia_naczynia.png', 415, 994, '#content')).then(function() {
            $( "#zestaw1" ).bind( "click", function() {
              alert( "User clicked on img" );
            });
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: what is `loadImage`, what is the value returned by it? it should return a promise object for this to work

Comment: BTW, if loadImage() returns promise interface as it should, you don't need to use $.when() here

Comment: I've moved `bind`ed event to `loadImage` and it works now